# Public WordPress Website unaccessible from inside active directory with same domain name, but simple html file is accessible

Tags: active-directory, .htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect

a client uses the same corporate domain for his internal network / office365 installation as for the public website.

The website and domain are hosted on a shared host, the site is serviced by me. After installing the internal network using the same domain, the website was, expectedly, not accessible from inside the corporate network. The company servicing the internal network has since modified the configuration of the internal domain controllers, including reconfiguring the name servers for the www. subdomain.

The shared host is 301 redirecting http:// requests to https:// requests and www. requests to no-www. requests and vice versa. It's using Apache.

Now the following is happening. From inside the corporate network (corp-domain.com), a simple index.php file hosted on the public site is accessible at https://www.corp-domain.com, and even at https://corp-domain.com, while the WordPress installation at the same location is not, and any request will throw a timed out error whether using the www. subdmain or not, even without using the default WordPress .htaccess to rewrite URLs.

What could be the reason here? Grateful for any idea.

Thanks!